# Run application by bat command in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run chrome by using bat command, but I need to check the path that chrome was installed on. Traditionally, Chrome will be installed on Program Files. However, I want to check the system (x86 or x64). So I write the bat command like:

```
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"(
    "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.youtube.com
)ELSE(
    "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.youtube.com
)
```

However, it didn't work. I cannot run chrome. If I write exact path:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.youtube.com
```

It works normally. What is wrong?

Comment: The help text (`if /?`) told you the correct syntax of the `if` command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing spaces.  Try:

```
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" (
    "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.youtube.com
) ELSE (
    "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.youtube.com
)
```

Comment: Works like charm :) Thanks! Spaces before and after scope are also important in bat file.

Comment: Sure. Stackoverflow said need to wait for 5 minutes later to set "accepted". It didn't let me do now :)

Answer (score 2):

You need spaces before and after the parentheses.